# How to get comparison between count and previous using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, count, logic

I want to compare two things current and previous, How can I achieve that can anyone help me
Thankyou in advance

```
import threading
import time
count = 1
def compare(a1,a2):
    print("Current value",a1)
    print("previous value",a2)

def increse():
    global count
    datestring = str(time.strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M"))
    filepath1 = datestring + '_' + str(count) + '.png'
    count += 1
    return filepath1  

def get_old():
    threading.Timer(0.5 * 60, get_old).start()
    a1 = increse()
    # Here how can I store current time as previous for comparision  
    print(a1)
    compare(a1,a2)
get_old()
```

Here thread running continuously ane get new a1 everytime , I want to get both current a1 and previous a1 ,how can I store previous value as a2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You can use a list to store the previous values and I'm also elaborating this code for your understanding**

```
import threading
import time

#New function added
def store(filepath1,lstfilepath1):
    lstfilepath1.append(filepath1)
    return lstfilepath1[len(lstfilepath1)-2:len(lstfilepath1)]

def compare(a1,a2):
    print("Current value",a1)
    print("previous value",a2)

def increse(count,lstfilepath1):

    datestring = str(time.strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M"))
    filepath1 = datestring + '_' + str(count) + '.png'
    a=store(filepath1,lstfilepath1)
    count += 1
    return a

def get_old(count,lstfilepath1):
    threading.Timer(0.5 * 60, get_old,(count,lstfilepath1,)).start()
    a1= increse(count,lstfilepath1)
    # Here how can I store current time as previous for comparision  
    #print(a1)
    compare(a1[1],a1[0])

count = 1
lstfilepath1=[]#new list added
lstfilepath1.append(0)

get_old(count,lstfilepath1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Am I missing something here? You are already using a global for count, so why not use a global for a1?

```
def get_old():
global a1
threading.Timer(0.5 * 60, get_old).start()
a2 = a1
a1 = increse()
# Here how can I store current time as previous for comparision  
print(a1)
compare(a1,a2)
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Prophacy , It working exactly what I want